# Tensorflow model's weight updated on sess.run

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am struggling with the fact that my weights in the model get updated when I run sess.run(*without reference to train step*).

I try to feed my model with variables to get the estimated outputs, but when I run the sess.run the weights get updated.

```
### in the training phase ####
X_eval, Y_eval, O_eval, W_eval, cost_eval, train_step_eval = sess.run([X, Y, O_out, W, cost, train_step], feed_dict={X:x_batch , Y:y_batch})

### when the training is finished (closed for loop) ###
print(W_eval)
Y_out, W_eval2 = sess.run([O_out, W], feed_dict = {X:labeled_features[:,: - n_labels], Y:labeled_features[:,- n_labels :]})
print(W_eval2)
```

When I compare W_eval and W_eval2 they are not the same, which I do not understand why.
Could you please point me to the right direction, why the weights are not the same?

```
'w3': array([[-2.9685912],
   [-3.215485 ],
   [ 3.8806837],
   [-3.331745 ],
   [-3.3904853]], dtype=float32

'w3': array([[-2.9700036],
   [-3.2168453],
   [ 3.8804765],
   [-3.3330843],
   [-3.3922129]], dtype=float32
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** Added W_eval assignment.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please show where you get `W_eval` from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```py
### in the training phase ####
X_eval, Y_eval, O_eval, W_eval, cost_eval, train_step_eval = sess.run([X, Y, O_out, W, cost, train_step], feed_dict={X:x_batch , Y:y_batch})

### when the training is finished (closed for loop) ###
print(W_eval)
Y_out, W_eval2 = sess.run([O_out, W], feed_dict = {X:labeled_features[:,: - n_labels], Y:labeled_features[:,- n_labels :]})
print(W_eval2)
```

still executes `train_step`. A simpler version to understand what is going on is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=42.)

train_step = a.assign(a + 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    value, _ = sess.run([a, train_step])  # will update a
    print(value)
    value = sess.run([a])  # will not update a
    print(value)
    value = sess.run([a])  # will not update a
    print(value)
```

gives the output

```
42.0
[43.0]
[43.0]
```

Another thing to check is if `x_batch == labeled_features[:,: - n_labels]` holds.

Comment: To make it clear, you might want to add that `W_eval` contains the value from _before_ the training step is executed in case both are returned via the the same `run` call.

Comment: Guys, thank you both very much for your time and effort. Now I understand, that the sess.run actually returns a previous iteration of the weights/variables. This is something I have not read anywhere, but now I know thanks to you, what to focus on. Thank you very much.